# Keeping data models on the client and server in sync?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, database-design

This is a question about application architecture. I'm working on a iOS client app and (RoR) server backend. It seems like I spend needless mental energy creating data models on the RoR server, serving that model as JSON (that part is easy enough from Ruby), creating objective-C data objects, and writing JSON/NSDictionary serializer/de-serializers for said class.

It seems like I should be able to just, write a data schema (in ruby, yaml, json, whatever), and get the ruby object, obj-c object, and json serialize/deserialize for both for free. Anyone have any thoughts on this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

look at the different libraries available. the one that works the best is RestKit. http://restkit.org/

RestKit allows you to easily translate a JSON API into coredata objects that are synced on the client. you can tell it what objects to update and how.

Comment: It looks like a cool project, but while it seems to give the serializers more or less for free, still seems like there's a lot of boilerplate code to write. Oh well, maybe I'll just have to go build a system like this if I want one.